# How to group common set of tables in Oracle sql developer in one schema user

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to group certain set of tables in one folder in sql developer. Please suggest me on how to do this.

For examples I have two sets of tables:

Set1:
1. Student
2. Course
3. CourseDesc
4. Faculty
5. City

Set2:
1. Person
2. Bank
3. Account
4. City

Currently I have created two separate schema users and created each set of tables in them. What I would like to do is, instead of creating new users for every set of tables, is their a way to group the tables under one folder in one schema.

Appreciate your valuable inputs.

Dex.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that SQL Developer doesn't offer such a feature (unlike TOAD's "Favorites", for example) - at least, I don't know how to do it. A possible *workaround* is to use prefix for tables that belong to the same set. For example:

- STU_STUDENT, STU_COURSE, STU_FACULTY
- BNK_PERSON, BNK_BANK, BNK_ACCOUNT

It it probably too late to do it for existing tables, but consider doing it in the future.